# Re-allocating array of structure with realloc?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, realloc

I'm practicing on structures, dynamic memory and file I/O but I can't understand what is wrong with this code. I suspect that the error is with realloc function. When I run the program after the file opening, the program crash. 
I check a lot of times and I suppose that is not a syntax related problem(especially with realloc).

Structure declaration:

```
#define MAXLENPATH 250
#define MAXSTRING 25

typedef struct
{
    int ID;
    char Name[MAXSTRING];
    char Surname[MAXSTRING];
    char code[MAXSTRING];
    int age;
}person;
```

Function to get record info:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Data.h"
#include "DataBase.h"

void initRecord(person *Person)
{
    printf("Insert ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &Person->ID);

    printf("Insert Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", Person->Name);

    printf("Insert Surname:\n");
    scanf("%s", Person->Surname);

    printf("Insert Age:\n");
    scanf("%d", &Person->age);

    printf("Insert code:\n");
    scanf("%s", Person->code);

}
```

Main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Data.h"
#include "DataBase.h"

int main(void) {

    FILE *ts;
    char *fpath=NULL;
    int pCount=1; //variable to hold database records count
    int i=0;
    int toAdd=0;
    person *personDB=NULL;

    fpath="C:\\Users\\Pio\\Desktop\\FILEOP\\MYTXT.txt";

    personDB = malloc(pCount*sizeof(person));

    //fill the database(in memory)
    i=0;
    while( i < pCount)
    {
        printf("Record %d\n",i+1);
        initRecord(&personDB[i]); //fill i-th database record
        printf("Record %d ID:%d Name:%s Surname:%s Age:%d Code:%s \n", i+1, personDB[i].ID, personDB[i].Name, personDB[i].Surname, personDB[i].age, personDB[i].code );
        i++;


        if(i == pCount) // check if all records are filled, then ask to user how many records wants and realloc new memory
        {
            printf("Insert element to add to database records:");
            scanf("%d", &toAdd);
            personDB=realloc(personDB, toAdd*(sizeof(person)) );
            pCount += toAdd;
        }

    }

    //Print structure on file
    if ((ts=fopen(fpath, "w")) != NULL)
    {
        puts("FILE OPENED");
        fprintf(ts,"************INFO****************\n");
        i=0;
        while (i < pCount)
        {

            fprintf(ts, "Record %d ID:%d Name:%s Surname:%s Age:%d Code:%s \n", i+1, personDB[i].ID, personDB[i].Name, personDB[i].Surname, personDB[i].age, personDB[i].code );

            i++;

        }
        fclose(ts);
    }
    else
        perror("ERROR:");

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You're in need of help from `gdb`, I assume. :)

Comment: The second argument to `realloc` is the new total amount of allocated memory in bytes, not the additional memory. It can be less than the original amount.

Comment: Previous size of `personDB` should be added to new size in `realloc` for additional memory.

Comment: You might want to assign the return value of realloc to a temp variable and check that it isn't NULL before assigning personDB to it. I don't know how realistic allocation failure is on a modern system, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @MOehm it works now, thanks a lot! Have you any tips to make my code more "elegant"?

Comment: @BobbySacamano you're right it's always good to check the function's return value , thanks for the tips

Comment: @SouravGhosh just type 0 (elements to add) so the condition becomes false and you can exit from while() loop